# magento 2 export not working , after clicking continue its redirect to the dashboard

Tags: magento2

Product CSV created in var folder but it's not getting the download. Or CSV file shows 302 error.

I tried all the solutions given for not working export. is there any other way?

1.expected result: It should download a CSV file

2.actual result: It only generates a file in the var folder but not getting a download.

Comment: check your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove deprecated "modules_disable_output" values from core_config_data,

Before run below query please take backup of core_config_data table.

> DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE
>   "advanced/modules_disable_output/%";

And clear cache

Hope it will work for you.